# Custom XAML Namespace in Powershell

Tags: wpf, powershell, xaml, visual-studio-2015, xml-namespaces

I'm trying to make a WPF app in Powershell using the [Material Design in XAML Toolkit](https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit) but I can't use properties from the "materialDesign" custom namespace. I've tried various ways to define the namespace but all gives the same error:

`"Exception calling "Load" with "1" argument(s): "Cannot set unknown member '{http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes}HintAssist.Hint'.""`

I have a Visual Studio project where I installed the Material Design Themes package through NuGet which works fine with the same property, but if I copy the XAML to be parsed in Powershell I can't seem to make it work.

As soon as I try to use the textbox property `materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Name"` it breaks.

### Powershell Code

```
Import-Module "$($PSScriptRoot)\MaterialDesignColors.dll"
Import-Module "$($PSScriptRoot)\MaterialDesignThemes.wpf.dll"

[xml]$xaml = @"
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
        Title="MainWindow" Width="1040" Height="495"

        TextElement.Foreground="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignBody}"
        Background="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignPaper}"
        TextElement.FontWeight="Medium"
        TextElement.FontSize="14"
        FontFamily="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Resources/Roboto/#Roboto"
        >

    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Dark.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Primary/MaterialDesignColor.Amber.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Accent/MaterialDesignColor.DeepPurple.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="27" Margin="142,266,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Name"/>
    </Grid>

</Window>

"@

$reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
$Window=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )

$Window.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```

### Visual Studio Project Code

Below is the code from the Visual Studio project where the HintAssist property works fine:

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="CreatePrinterWPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Width="1040" Height="495"

    TextElement.Foreground="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignBody}"
    Background="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignPaper}"
    TextElement.FontWeight="Medium"
    TextElement.FontSize="14"
    FontFamily="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Resources/Roboto/#Roboto"
    >
<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="27" Margin="142,266,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Name"/>
</Grid>
```

App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="CreatePrinterWPF.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CreatePrinterWPF"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Dark.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Primary/MaterialDesignColor.Amber.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Accent/MaterialDesignColor.DeepPurple.xaml" />

        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

The desired outcome is for the textbox to have a 
[faded text in it until the user enters something](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhNKv.png).

I can't seem to find any resources on using XAML namespaces from compiled library files in Powershell, it would be greatly appreciated if someone could help me out.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve the problem.

If I define the namespace as below it works, as long as the DLL file is named the same:

```
xmlns:materialDesign="clr-namespace:MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;assembly=MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf"
```