# Windows forms problem - Unable to load Windows.Markup.XamlReader

Tags: powershell

Please can you help me?

The code makes this output error:
**Unable to load Windows.Markup.XamlReader**

This code is made by Microsoft Visual Studio - Project WPF APP

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('presentationframework')
[xml]$XAML = @"

<Window 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Label Name="label1" Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="222,102,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="92"/>
        <Label Name="label2" Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="222,177,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="92"/>
        <Label Name="label3" Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="222,246,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="92"/>
        <TextBox Name="text1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="369,110,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" TextChanged="text1_TextChanged_1"/>
        <TextBox Name="text2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="369,185,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" RenderTransformOrigin="0.483,4.29"/>
        <TextBox Name="text3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="369,254,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" RenderTransformOrigin="0.483,4.29"/>
        <Button Name="button1" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="572,168,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="131" Height="46"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>


"@
#Read XAML
$reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml) 
try{$Form=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )}
catch{Write-Host "Unable to load Windows.Markup.XamlReader"; exit}

# Store Form Objects In PowerShell
$xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | ForEach-Object {Set-Variable -Name ($_.Name) -Value $Form.FindName($_.Name)}

#Show Form
$Form.ShowDialog() | out-null
```

Comment: The reason it displays ```Unable to load Windows.Markup.XamlReader``` is because that's what your error handler is doing in the ```catch``` block. If you let the actual exception propogate up you'll get this instead: ```MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "Load" with "1" argument(s): "Cannot set unknown member '{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006}Ignorable'."```

Comment: This question has an answer that might give you a head-start - it looks like you need to specify the appropriate assembly name in the ```xmlns``` declaration - https://stackoverflow.com/a/45923461/3156906